Entrywise $\infty$-norm of squared difference of square roots of matrices
For a positive $n \times n$ definite real matrix $M$ we denote by $\sqrt{M}$ the positive square root of $M$. For an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ denote its entrywise infinity norm by
$$\|A\|_{\infty,\infty} = \max_{1 \leq i,j \leq n}|a_{ij}|.$$
Given two positive definite real-valued $n \times n$ matrices $A$, $B$ is it necessarily true that
$$\|(\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B})^2\|_{\infty,\infty} \leq \|A-B\|_{\infty,\infty}?$$

A counterexample:
$$\sqrt A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 4 & 2 \\
 2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right),\quad
\sqrt B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 1 & -2 \\
 -2 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
Then $A=5\sqrt A$ and $B=5\sqrt B$, so that the ratio of the left-hand side of the conjectured inequality to its right-hand side is $5/4>1$.

A slightly more conceptual approach than Iosif’s explicit counterexample: suppose $U$ is a self-adjoint unitary. Then $U = A - B$ for some orthogonal projections $A, B$. Thus, $\sqrt{A} = A$ and $\sqrt{B} = B$, so the LHS is $\|U^2\|_{\infty, \infty} = \|I\|_{\infty, \infty} = 1$ and the RHS is $\|U\|_{\infty, \infty}$. Thus, it suffices to find a self-adjoint unitary whose entrywise infinity norm is strictly smaller than $1$. An easy example is,
$$U = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$
Remark: If, by “positive definite”, you require the matrices to be strictly positive, then the above won’t work as is, but you can easily fix this by changing $A$ and $B$ to $A + \epsilon I$ and $B + \epsilon I$, respectively, for sufficiently small $\epsilon > 0$. By continuity, this will still yield a counterexample to your proposed inequality.

"suppose $U$ is a self-adjoint unitary. Then $U = A - B$ for some orthogonal projections $A, B$." Can you say how this is proved?

@IosifPinelis Spectral theorem. Every self-adjoint unitary has its spectrum contained in ${\pm 1}$. (This is extremely standard in operator algebras, operator theory, and spectral theory.)

@IosifPinelis I guess $A=(I+U)/2, B=(I-U)/2$ works, as $A^2=(I+2U+U^2)/4=(I+2U+UU^)/4=(I+U)/2=A$ and analogously $B^2=B$, moreover, $A=A^,B=B^*$, so $A,B$ are indeed projectors.

Moreover, this approach shows (by taking tensor products of these $2\times 2$ matrices $U$) that it is impossible to find a constant $C$ independent of $n$ such that $||(\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B})^2||{\infty,\infty}\leq C||A-B||{\infty,\infty}$.

@DavidGao : Thank you for your response.

@ssssnnnn : Thank you for your response.
